# error about 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, list, split, nltk, stemming

The code below does not run. The parameter passed to the function is a list of strings.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```
base_train = [
('este trabalho e agradável','alegria'),
('gosto de ficar no seu aconchego','alegria'),
('fiz a adesão ao curso hoje porque eu gostei','alegria'),
('eu sou admirada por muitos','alegria'),
('adoro como você e','alegria'),
('adoro seu cabelo macio','alegria')

def apply_Stemmer(text):
stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
sentence_no_Stemming = []
for (words, sentiment) in text:
    com_Stemming = [str(stemmer.stem(p)) for p in words.split()]
    sentence_no_Stemming.append((with_Stemming, sentiment))
return sentence_no_Stemming

sentence_with_Stem_train = apply_Stemmer(base_train)
```

Comment: I don't see an issue here. Please make sure that the code you execute and pasted here are same.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
for (words, sentiment) in text:
    com_Stemming = [str(stemmer.stem(p)) for p in words.split()]
```

The error tells you that `words` in the iterations is are lists, so you can't
use the `str.split()` method on them. Try:

```
for (words, sentiment) in text:
    com_Stemming = [str(stemmer.stem(p)) for p in words]
```